# How to embed a PDF in HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, servlets, browser-plugin

We would like to show the PDF document in an HTML page after retrieving it from the database via a servlet's `doGet` method.

Can anyone share some snippets on how to achieve this?

Comment: "Show" how? Using a browser plug-in that is installed on the user's system?

Comment: You just need to return the appropriate mimetype in the response header.

Comment: You will need to use the object, embed or iframe tag to do a separate http request for the content

Comment: @mplungjan - How to retrieve the content in a iframe tag?

Comment: @symcbean - I am returning an appropriate mimetype for this doc as part of the http response

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Non-html content apart from images needs to be retrieved using an object, embed or iframe tag

1. **iframe**: `<iframe src="somepage.pdf"></iframe>`
2. **object/embed**: `<object src="somepage.pdf"><embed src="somepage.pdf"></embed></object>`

somepage.pdf could be somepage.jsp?filename=somepage&mimetype=application/pdf

Here is an interesting link [How to Embed Microsoft Office or PDF Documents in Web Pages](http://labnol.blogspot.com/2007/03/how-to-embed-microsoft-office-or-pdf.html)

and here is a [stackoverflow search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=embed%20pdf%20html)

Comment: I need to use inline style elements from the parent document in the child document. Iframe doesn’t allow this. Would this work with embed or object?

Comment: Unlikely. If cross domain it will also not work. If not, then iframe should work. Ask a separate question

Comment: same domain. But the question is already asked and it's answers only provide response for using external stylesheets.

Comment: So why can't you use iFrame? You can copy and insert the parent's stylesheets into the iframe when loading

Comment: In fact I don't need an iframe. This is for a single tag which is pre. The content require a special editor that I wrote myself and it's very difficult to edit it. So I thought the best was to split that part for the main document. Also the solution should not require visitors to enable JavaScript.

Comment: When i'm trying these, it's start downloading the docx file, is it because i'm not on a server (offline), or im' missing something?

Comment: Likely your browser is not set up to use word embedded.

Comment: This will work only for PDF, for any Microsoft Office format it will download the file. I even tested it on Edge, and still I didn't managed to View a .docx file. Did anyone managed to make this work??

Answer (score 10):

Google docs viewer can handle this.

try

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            *{margin:0;padding:0}
            html, body {height:100%;width:100%;overflow:hidden}
        </style>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <?php
                 $url = $_GET['url'];
             ?>
        <title><?php echo $url; ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=<?=urlencode($url)?>&embedded=true"  style="position: absolute;width:100%; height: 100%;border: none;"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the only way that i found and working.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a pure HTML version of the document (for fast rendering and cross browser support), you can go through Docspad. Docspad helps embedding all the different popular document formats into your web application. http://docspad.com

Comment: Docspad is dead: "We will no longer support Docspad services effective October 19, 2014"