# Word document is downloaded instead of displaying - HTML

Tags: html, iframe

I'm trying to display a word document on my page and this is what I tried after searching online : 
`<iframe src="file.docx" width="600px" height="400px" > </iframe>`

But the Iframe appears empty and the file is downloaded instead of being displayed. Also I get the warning like :
`Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`

Any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to embed a document in HTML page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565759/how-to-embed-a-document-in-html-page)

Answer (score 4):

You can use **Google doc viewer** for displaying pdf, doc, docx inside an iframe

`<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url={url}&embedded=true"> </iframe>`

I haven't used this but Microsoft online doc viewer can also be used as explained [here](http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-docs-viewer-alternative/26591/)

`http://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=http://img.labnol.org/di/Word.docx`

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Application Executer</title>
<style>
#frm
{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<object id="frm" data="Circuit.pdf">You do not have Word installed on your machine</object>
</body>
</html>
```

data="your file address" dont't forget css for full size,for docx use this: https://docs.google.com/viewer/ or convert it to pdf