# MVC: How to open .doc file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this partial view that displays links to documents;

```
@model IList<DocumentLineViewModel>
<tr>
    <td class="leftCell" style="width: 150px;">
        <label>Documents</label></td>
    <td class="rightCell" id="documentCell">
        @if (Model.Any(x => x.CurrentUrlFlag))
        {
            foreach (var document in Model)
            {
                 <a target="_blank" href="@document.CurrentUrl">
                     @document.CategoryName
                 </a>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <span>Not Entered</span>
        }
    </td>
</tr>
```

If the document is a pdf it works fine, I can view the document.
If the document is word (or excel) I get this unwelcome prompt;
[image]

How do I stop this?

EDIT
One way I tried was to embed the document in a popup but this did not work;

```
@model IList<DocumentLineViewModel>
<tr>
    <td class="leftCell" style="width: 150px;">
        <label>Documents</label></td>
    <td class="rightCell" id="documentCell">
        @if (Model.Any(x => x.CurrentUrlFlag))
        {
            foreach (var document in Model)
            {
                if (document.CurrentUrl.ToUpper().EndsWith("PDF"))
                {
                    <a target="_blank" href="@document.CurrentUrl" class="btn">
                        @document.CategoryName
                    </a>
                }
                else
                {
                    <a href="#show-document" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">@document.CategoryName</a>
                    <div class="modal fade" id="show-document" style="display: none">
                        <object src="@document.CurrentUrl"><embed src="@document.CurrentUrl"></embed></object>
@*                        <iframe src="@document.CurrentUrl"></iframe>*@
                    </div>
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <span>Not Entered</span>
        }
    </td>
</tr>
```

The popup appeared, but the content did not show the document.

Comment: What are you trying to do? A PDF will open in the browser, thus no prompt to download. The browser has no native functionality for viewing `docx` files and so they must be downloaded. As far as I know, you can't override the prompt because it is a safety feature on the users' side.

Comment: That is what I am trying to do, and the answer is that it can't be done it would seem.

Comment: you can try with [word viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/tr-tr/download/details.aspx?id=4)

Comment: @arame3333 Siva Gopal has an interesting point in the answer below, if you can find a way to invoke a web document viewer such as Google Docs Viewer, that would certainly be an interesting way around your issue. Your 'links' would probably need to use JavaScript to upload the file to the document viewer via AJAX and then you could probably open the response in an iframe or a modal window or something, that'd be quite cool.

Comment: My attempted solution did not work, see the edited question to see what I did.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sippy suggested, AFAIK there is no native support except PDFs offered by browsers to render documents.

If you can expose your documents for few converters available you may do that as shown in following links:

[Google Docs Viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer)

[SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565759/how-to-embed-a-document-in-html-page)

[Display word document on browser](http://forums.asp.net/t/1908893.aspx?Display%20a%20word%20document%20on%20browser) (Hope this may help you to an extent)

Comment: The Google Docs Viewer does not work, I suspect because the URL is not accessable outside of the VPN I am using.
The IFrame and Embed solutions I can't get to work. I have edited my question so you can see what I have done.

Comment: Like I said you would need to upload the document from where it is using Ajax as it won't be accessible :)