# how to embed ms word into web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I embed MS Word into my HTML page and use it as a content editor in all browsers like IE, Firefox, Chrome,... .

For example, I want to use MS Word instead another content editor in web pages like CKEditor,niceeditor and ....

Please  help me.

I buy an ActiveX from [edrawsoft.com](http://edrawsoft.com) for using MS Word as content editor but, works only in IE.

For example , i want something like this office.live.com/start/Word.aspx?omkt=en-US

Comment: you mean it works on IE but Chrome and FF?

Comment: Try the mentioned thread. I hope it may be helpful. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565759/how-to-embed-a-document-in-html-page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565759/how-to-embed-a-document-in-html-page)

Comment: i want use MS Word as a text editor in html page

Comment: A google search with the title leads to multiple possible ways of doing this.

Comment: For example , i want something like this https://office.live.com/start/Word.aspx?omkt=en-US

Comment: OP wants to use MS Word as the IDE for HTML pages. Something I would never recommend, not in a million years. Although you can set hyperlinks and whatnot, Word was never designed to be an editor of web pages, if you want some sort of nice UI you can try one of the many free online **Content Management Systems** like WordPress.

Comment: look at this , please
office.live.com/start/Word.aspx?omkt=en-US

Comment: @majidzarharan — That doesn't embed MS Word, it rebuilds it from the ground up in JavaScript. Teaching you how to build a complex word processor in JavaScript is far too broad a topic for SO.

Comment: Just to clarify the other comments: you **can't** embed the actual Word on a web page so that it would work on all browsers. It's simply impossible.

Comment: If it's for use on preconfigured computers, edrawsoft explains it here: https://www.edrawsoft.com/install-activex-control.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@majidzarharan — That doesn't embed MS Word, it rebuilds it from the ground up in JavaScript. Teaching you how to build a complex word processor in JavaScript is far too broad a topic for SO. 
[Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin) answerd.
thanks a lot.