# displying docx file data using html

Tags: html, angularjs, css

hi i need to display doc/docs and PDF file in my html page. i tried following tag PDF file is displaying content but doc/docs file is not displaying please help me.

Comment: Try with Iframe, and google or microsoft doc viewer.

Comment: showing your code here at least we can see what you have tried so far.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565759/how-to-embed-a-document-in-html-page