# How to embed MS Word into a XPages

Tags: xpages

Is it possible to embed somehow MS Word object in XPages? I would like to use MS word as preview at the same XPages. There will be some filed then What I enter into field will update MS Word just like you see preview in MS Word before what you would like to print

I just wonder even if it is possible or not? Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Paul is right that this question is not specific to XPages, but it also depends on what you exactly try to do. In my company we create a lot of Word documents by merging information from a Domino database into a MS Word template using XDocReport (https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport). That's a library I can highly recommend. The generated file is stored in another document and offered to the user for download. POI4XPages might also be able to do what you need.

Answer (score 2):

It's unlikely this will be specific to XPages. My golden rule on "how do I do x in XPages" is search "how do I do x on the web" and go from there. This StackOverflow question is as good a starting point as any. [How to embed a document in HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565759/how-to-embed-a-document-in-html-page)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably entering a world of hurt down that road.

The old options:

- OLE embedding was Internet explorer only (not Chrome, Firefox, Safari or Edge) and Windows only. Required Office on the workstation and is typically disabled for security (nothing of that has to do with XPages as backend).
- Word to Html (requires word or OpenOffice on the server) is a Pita.

Your mobile users will not be happy or the MAC folks. Try to stick to a HTML editor and render that part.

But if you have to:

- [Poi4Xpages](https://poi4xpages.openntf.org/) allows rendering of MS office documents from XPages app (one way output)
- [WebDAV for Domino](https://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=editDocument&name=WebDAV+for+IBM+Domino) allows round-trip editing of attachments in Domino
- Skip the Word part and render directly to PDF - at least you get print fidelity. There's a [series on that](https://wissel.net/blog/2012/04/extracting-data-from-domino-into-pdf-using-xslt-and-xslfo-part-1.html)

Answer (score 0):

POI4XPages will allow you to send Domino data to bookmarks in Word. From there users can download the Word doc or you can output to pdf.

Comment: as far as i understand POI does not solve my case. What i mean is to realtime preview in XPages. I fill some form fields then at the same time a word document previed in XPages will show what i enter

Comment: I looked up then i could not find any answer. is there any other way to send data in to Word except bookmark method in POI or other solutions are possible.